# Why are maximal existence intervals of IVP open?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, initial-value-problems

In my current ODE lecture we recently introduced the proposition

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be open, $f: D
> \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and admit a local
>   Lipschitz-condition in it's second component. Then there exists for
>   every initial value $(t_0, y_0) \in D$ an open interval $I$ with $t_0 \in I$ and a solution $y$ on $I$ to the IVP
>
> $$\begin{cases} y' = f(t, y) & (t, y) \in D \\ y(t_0) = y_0 \end{cases}$$
>
> such that for every interval $J$ with $t_0 \in J$ and solution $z$ on
>   $J$ to the IVP we already have
>
> - $J \subseteq I$
> - $z = y|_J$
>
> The interval $I$ is called **maximal interval of existence** for the
>   IVP.

**Proof:** (Sketch)

> 1. We define
>
>    $$t^* = \sup \{t : t \geq t_0 \text{ and there exists a solution on } [t_0, t]\}$$
>      $$t_* = \inf \{t : t \leq t_0 \text{ and there exists a solution on } [t, t_0]\}$$
>
>    and prove (by the local Picard-Lindelöf) that this already gives a solution $y$ on $(t_*, t^*)$ (notice that we chose the open interval here).
> 2. Now exactly:
>
>    Let $z: J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a solution to the IVP on $J \subseteq I$. In particular $z$ is a solution to the IVP on $[\min(t_0, t), \max(t_0, t)]$ for every $t \in J$. From local Picard-Lindelöf we already have $z = y|_J$.

**Question:** Now I'm curious about the part "... on $J \subseteq I$." How do we only look at intervals with $J \subseteq I$. In particular why isn't it possible that the solution in step $1$ is defined on $[t_*, t^*]$ (closed). Am I missing something or does this require extra work?

**EDIT:** The first page of [this document](http://site.iugaza.edu.ps/asakka/files/2010/02/sec2.4.pdf) has the theorem in it (no proof) and the text above describes the process as well.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a function that is differentiable at $t$ must be defined in some open interval around $t$, because the definition of derivative requires a (two-sided) limit.
In order for $y$ to be a solution of the differential equation $y' = f(t,y)$, that derivative $y'$ must exist.  So solutions of differential equations quite naturally "live" on open intervals.

That said, it is quite possible that as $t$ approaches an endpoint of the maximal interval of existence, the (one-sided) limit of a solution exists.  It just won't give you a point in $D$.

Comment: I don't think the derivative argument is working here, since we also had examples of solutions on closed intervals (look at the definition of $t^*$ for example). We can always look at the integral equation corresponding to the IVP. The integral equation is defined for continuous functions.

Comment: Take a look at my edit.

Comment: I came up with a solution: Every closed existence interval is contained in an open existence interval. To see this we can take a closed existence interval $[a, b]$. As continuous function the corresponding solution $y$ is bounded on $[a, b]$. Now we can look at the IVP with initial value $t_0 = b$ and $y_0 = y(b)$.  [...]

Comment: [...] This will give another solution on $[b - \delta, b + \delta]$, which can be used to expand the original solution $y$. This process (on each end of the interval) gives a new solution on $[a - \delta_1, b + \delta_2]$. The interval $[a, b]$ is contained in the interior of $[a - \delta_1, b + \delta_2]$. The union of all these open existence interval is of course open again.